# Spark scala use spark-mongo connector to upsert

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark

Is there any way to upsert Mongo Collection with spark-mongo connector based on a certain field in dataframe ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of [MongoDB Connector for Spark](https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/master/) version 1.1+ (currently version 2.2) 
when you execute `save()` as below:

```
dataFrameWriter.write.mongo()
dataFrameWriter.write.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql").save()
```

If a dataframe contains an `_id` field, the data will be [upserted](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#upsert-option). Which means any existing documents with the same `_id` value will be updated and new documents without existing `_id` value in the collection will be inserted.

See also [MongoDB Spark SQL](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-spark/blob/master/doc/1-sparkSQL.md) for more information and snippets.

Comment: Thanks , i was hoping there is a way of doing this based on another field in my dataset

Comment: @Wan, Thank you.! your solution helped me.. :)

Answer (score 4):

To replace documents based on unique key constraint, use replaceDocument and shardKey option. Default shardKey is {_id: 1}.
https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/master/configuration/

```py
df.write.format('com.mongodb.spark.sql') \
  .option('collection', 'target_collection') \
  .option('replaceDocument', 'true') \
  .option('shardKey', '{"date": 1, "name": 1, "resource": 1}') \
  .mode('append') \
  .save()
```

replaceDocument=false option makes your document merged based on the shardKey.

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-spark/blob/c9e1bc58cb509021d7b7d03367776b84da6db609/src/main/scala/com/mongodb/spark/MongoSpark.scala#L120-L141

Comment: I am getting this exception when I try to upsert when replaceDocument is true //com.mongodb.MongoBulkWriteException: Bulk write operation error on server ... message='After applying the update, the (immutable) field '_id' was found to have been altered to _id: ObjectId('5f80331981f3601291e04a1c')// and when replaceDocument is false // Performing an update on the path '_id' would modify the immutable field '_id''. Any ideas?

Comment: I needed to explicitely drop the _id column then it worked. This shd be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try option replaceDocument

```
df.select("_id").withColumn("aaa", lit("ha"))
  .write
  .option("collection", collectionName)
  .option("replaceDocument", "false")
  .mode(SaveMode.Append)
  .format("mongo")
  .save()
```

I dont know why in mongo document can not find any document for this option

Answer (score 0):

With some digging on [mongo-spark's source](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-spark/blob/0f34512b91eaf5e7e89c0380284fd7068a32838d/src/main/scala/com/mongodb/spark/MongoSpark.scala#L147), here's a simple hack to add the feature of upsert on certain fields, to `MongoSpark.save` method:

```
// add additional keys parameter
def save[D](dataset: Dataset[D], writeConfig: WriteConfig, keys: List[String]): Unit = {
    val mongoConnector = MongoConnector(writeConfig.asOptions)
    val dataSet = dataset.toDF()
    val mapper = rowToDocumentMapper(dataSet.schema)
    val documentRdd: RDD[BsonDocument] = dataSet.rdd.map(row => mapper(row))
    val fieldNames = dataset.schema.fieldNames.toList
    val queryKeyList = keys.isEmpty match {
      case true => keys
      case false => BsonDocument.parse(writeConfig.shardKey.getOrElse("{_id: 1}")).keySet().asScala.toList
    }
    // the rest remains the same
    // ...
}
```